# Working with Generic Methods in Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, methods, interface

Please help me correct this code.

I am having a compiler error in the class

```
public interface IGenericSaveRepository
{
    void Save<TEntity>(int id, ICollection<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class;
}


public class GenericSaveRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class,IGenericSaveRepository
{
    private IUnitofWork<TEntity> _unitofWork;
    private NaijaSchoolsContext _context;
    public GenericSaveRepository(NaijaSchoolsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _unitofWork = new UnitofWork<TEntity>(_context);
    }
    public void Save(int id, ICollection<TEntity> entities)
    {
        foreach (var entity1 in entities)
        {
            //entity.Insert(entity1);
            _unitofWork.Entity.Insert(entity1);
        }
    }
}


public class RatingRepo : GenericRepository<Rating>
{
    private IGenericSaveRepository gen;
    private readonly NaijaSchoolsContext _context;
    public RatingRepo(NaijaSchoolsContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    public void Save(School school,Rating rating)
    {

        List<Rating> ratings = new List<Rating>();
        ratings.Add(rating);
        gen = new GenericSaveRepository<Rating>(_context);
        gen.Save(23, ratings);
    }
}
```

This line  `gen = new GenericSaveRepository<Rating>(_context);` doesn't allow me to have Rating specified as a concrete type.

How can I do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: does Rating implement IGenericSaveRepository ?

Comment: Is there a difference between GenericRepository<T> and GenericSaveRepository<T> or was this a typo?
Also code of Rating class is missing, please proivde.

Comment: No it doesnt implement it @Selman22

Comment: then why would you expect this code to work?

Comment: Yes there is a Difference between between them @user3046593

Comment: i believe there should be a way..it should work @Selman22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should remove your compile error .. see gen implementation if you don't want Rating must implement IGenericSaveRepository

```
  public class RatingRepo : GenericRepository<Rating>
        {
            private GenericSaveRepository<Rating> gen;
            private readonly NaijaSchoolsContext _context;
            public RatingRepo(NaijaSchoolsContext context)
                : base(context)
            {
                _context = context;

            }

            public void Save(School school, Rating rating)
            {

                List<Rating> ratings = new List<Rating>();
                ratings.Add(rating);
                gen = new GenericSaveRepository<Rating>(_context);
                gen.Save(23, ratings);
            }
        }
```

Update : Complete implementation

```
public interface IGenericSaveRepository
    {
        void Save<TEntity>(int id, ICollection<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class;
    }


    public class GenericSaveRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        private UnitofWork<TEntity> _unitofWork;
        private NaijaSchoolsContext _context;
        public GenericSaveRepository(NaijaSchoolsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _unitofWork = new UnitofWork<TEntity>(_context);
        }
        public void Save(int id, ICollection<TEntity> entities)
        {
            foreach (var entity1 in entities)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public class UnitofWork<T>
    {
        public UnitofWork(NaijaSchoolsContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    internal interface IUnitofWork<T>
    {
    }

    public class NaijaSchoolsContext
    {
    }

    public class GenericRepository<T>
    {
        protected GenericRepository(NaijaSchoolsContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Rating 
    {
    }

    public class School
    {
    }
```

Comment: You arent implementing the IGenericSaveRepository from the GenericSaveRepository class. The Save method needs concrete implementation in GenericSaveRepository class

Comment: sorry then u have no option my dear friend but to implement IGenericSaveRepository in Rating class..

Comment: The problem is Rating must be convertible to IGenericSaveRepository in order to use it as parameter TEntity in generic class GenericSaveRepository<TEntity>, so either implement interface in rating class or simply remove it .. I hope this explain will help :)

Comment: thanks am finding am over-designing.. i will use KISS

Answer (score 1):

`Rating` must implement `IGenericSaveRepository` in order for that to compile.

`public class GenericSaveRepository<TEntity>` **where TEntity** : class,**IGenericSaveRepository**

Comment: I do not want Rating to implement the IGenericSaveRepository. Any way

Comment: but you want this: gen = new GenericSaveRepository<Rating>(_context); to compile..

Comment: I think the intention of Amirs answer is lost:
where TEntity : class,IGenericSaveRepository
is wrong, it should only be TEntity: class
Btw I try to avoid doing generics with only "class" definition, how about maybe defining an IEntity type, that for example provides the key field, at least that's what I often need in repos. Then it's also more clear, what is really meant with the generic field.

Comment: Yes I do . so what can I do

Comment: dows it not work when you have this line:
public class GenericSaveRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class

???
if not, post the code of the lart 2 classes please

Comment: @user3046593 I think the UOW has the "real" constrain to IGenericSaveRepository, and since the GenericSaveRepository<T> uses it then they are pretty coupled.

Comment: The Reason I have GenericRepository<Rating> extend RatingRepo is for me to get my context. These Classes are in my DataLayer Project while the Rating class in in the Business Domain. The Business Domain already is referenced by the Data Layer already. Is it possible for you to ignore these classes : IUnitofWork<TEntity>, GenericRepository and NaijaSchoolsContext while solving the problem for me?